# sprintf buffer issue, wrong assignment to char array

Tags: c++

I got an issue with sprintf buffer. 
As you can see in the code down below I'm saving with sprintf a char array to the buffer, so pFile can check if there's a file named like that in the folder. If it's found, the buffer value will be assigned to timecycles[numCycles], and numCycles will be increased. Example: timecycles[0] = "timecyc1.dat". It works well, and as you can see in the console output it recognizes that there are only timecyc1.dat and timecyc5.dat in the folder. But as long as I want to read timecycles with a for loop, both indexes have the value "timecyc9.dat", eventhough it should be "timecyc1.dat" for timecycles[0] and "timecyc5.dat" for timecycles[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kamcd.png). Second thing is, how can I write the code so readTimecycles() returns char* timecycles, and I could just initialize it in the main function with char* timecycles[9] = readTimecycles() or anything like that?

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kamcd.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

char* timecycles[9];

void readTimecycles()
{
char buffer[256];
int numCycles = 0;
FILE* pFile = NULL;

for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    sprintf(buffer, "timecyc%d.dat", i);
    pFile = fopen(buffer, "r");

    if (pFile != NULL)
    {
        timecycles[numCycles] = buffer;
        numCycles++;
        std::cout << buffer << std::endl; //to see if the buffer is correct
    }

}
   for (int i = 0; i < numCycles; i++)
   {
    std::cout << timecycles[i] << std::endl; //here's the issue with timecyc9.dat
   }
}

int main()
{
readTimecycles();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the assignment

```
timecycles[numCycles] = buffer;
```

you make ***all*** pointers point to the *same* buffer, since you only have a single `buffer`.

Since you're programming in C++ you could easily solve your problem by using `std::string` instead.

---

If I would remake your code into something a little-more C++-ish and less C-ish, it could look something like

```
std::array<std::string, 9> readTimeCycles()
{
    std::array<std::string, 9> timecycles;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < timecycles.size(); ++i)
    {
        // Format the file-name
        std::string filename = "timecyc" + std::to_string(i + 1) + ".dat";

        std::ifstream file(filename);
        if (file)
        {
            // File was opened okay
            timecycles[i] = filename;
        }
    }

    return timecycles;
}
```

References:

- [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)
- [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)
- [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)
- [`std::ifstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem is that your notion of a string doesn't match what a 'char array' is in C++. In particular you think that because you assign `timecycles[numCycles] = buffer;` somehow the chars of the char array are copied. But in C++ all that is being copied is a pointer, so `timecycles` ends up with multiple pointers to **the same buffer**. And that's not to mention the problem you will have that when you exit the `readTimecycles` function. At that point you will have multiple pointers to a buffer which **no longer exists** as it gets destroyed when you exit the `readTimecycles` function.

The way to fix this is to use C++ code that does match your expectations. In particular a `std::string` will copy in the way you expect it to. Here's how you can change your code to use `std::string`

```
#include <string>

std::string timecycles[9];

timecycles[numCycles] = buffer; // now this really does copy a string
```